# Application controller in winforms

Tags: winforms, design-patterns

I have to write a multiple form application that is used to manipulate the state of an object that represents a sporting event.

There are many different states the object can be in and depending on the state i will need to display a certain form or enable or disable controls on a form, I've read that an application controler can be used to better organise the work flow in a complex windows forms applicaiton, are there any good examples of an implementation of an application controller than someone can point me to ? or would there be a better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example, it seems to be a right one: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2009/04/18/decoupling-workflow-and-forms-with-an-application-controller/